# Proof of Proposition 3 in Serre's book "Linear Representation of Finite Groups"

Tags: representation-theory, proof-explanation, characters

> **Proposition 3.** Let $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ be a linear representation of $G$, and let $\chi$ be its character. Let $\chi^2_\sigma$ be the character of the symmetric square $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ of $V$, and let $\chi_\alpha^2$ be that of $\operatorname{Alt}^2(V)$. 
>   For each $s \in G$, we have \begin{align} \chi_\sigma^2 &= \frac{1}{2} (\chi(s)^2 + \chi(s^2)) \\ \chi_\alpha^2 &= \frac{1}{2} (\chi(s)^2 - \chi(s^2)) \\  \end{align} and $\chi_\sigma^2 + \chi_\alpha^2 = \chi^2$.

Serre starts with his proof taking a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $\rho_s$ and justified it with the observation that $\rho_s$ can be represented by a unitary matrix and refers to subsection 1.3. Unitary matrices are diagonalizable by the Spectral Theorem, as unitary matrices are normal too, so I am okay with this part.

In mentioned subsection, we assumed that the vector $V$ was endowed with a scalar product. However, **this is not mentioned in the hypothesis of Proposition 3**.

Could someone explain me if the argument is wrong resp. incomplete? Thank you!

Comment: You can always endow $V$ with a scalar product, and you can make the scalar product equivariant by averaging over the (discrete) group $G$.

Comment: Ah, because $V \simeq \mathbb{C}^n$ and we know that $\mathbb{C}^n$ has a scalar product, so $V$ does as well, is that correct? And could you please explain what an equivariant vector space is?

Comment: Equivariant means $\langle g.v,g.w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$. You can do this by choosing any inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and define $\langle v,w\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_g(g.v,g.w)$.